# join two query not by inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
$query1 = "SELECT id, ac, aa FROM tbl_ac WHERE ac = ? AND aa = ?";
```

and

```
$query2 = "SELECT id, cc FROM tbl_cc WHERE cc = ?";
```

What is the best equivalent of those two query in just one query? I can't use `INNER JOIN` with this because each table doesn't have any relations.

I just want to verify if `ac`, `aa` and `cc` exists in my database.

Comment: if the two tables are not related it is probably better to not try to merge their results

Comment: but is there equivalent?

Comment: A one query for this two query.

Comment: Please specify what do you want in output so we can make one query accordingly.

Comment: @Defensor yes thank you, that makes it much clearer. Have you thought about making each query its own function?

Comment: @JohnKane - Yup I quite thought of it, but for the sake of curiousness I thought is it possible in just one liner query.

Comment: What should the result(s) look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one query for this you can do it like this:

```
SELECT id, ac, aa, NULL as cc FROM tbl_ac WHERE ac = ? AND aa = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT id, NULL, NULL, cc FROM tbl_cc WHERE cc = ?
```

but I don't recomend.

---

If the queries are not linked in any way, you should do the two queries.

Comment: Thanks for this, may I know the explaination why I shouldn't?

Comment: Databases is all about relations. Joining two things that are not related is not the better way to do it. On the other side, you just access to the database one time and could improve performance so, you do what you want :)

Answer (score 3):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/779da/1

You could also do:

```
select *
from tbl_ac, tbl_cc
where ac = 1 AND aa = 1 AND cc = 1
```

(you could use an EXISTS or a COUNT(*) if that was going to bring back heaps of data)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, ac, aa FROM tbl_ac WHERE ac = ? AND aa = ?  
AND EXISTS(SELECT id, cc FROM tbl_cc WHERE cc = ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

If only some of the tables has the relation, you can use LEFT JOIN, which will join the tables and fill in NULL, where it has no relation.

```
$query = "
 SELECT tbl_ac.id, tbl_ac.ac, tbl_ac.aa 
 FROM tbl_ac
 LEFT JOIN tbl_cc ON ( tbl_cc.cc = tbl_ac.ac ) 
";
```

Comment: But these two tables literally doesn't have any relation at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_ac WHERE ac = ? AND aa = ?)
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_cc WHERE cc = ?)
```

Will return TRUE if both `EXISTS` predicates return TRUE, and FALSE otherwise. Note that you don't need to specify columns in an `EXISTS` subquery. The `EXISTS` predicate only tests for the existence of rows.